# 'Bson: Borrow<T> is not satisifed' error in simple CRUD post function

Tags: mongodb, rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio, rust-axum

I have following Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Bson: Borrow<News>` is not satisfied                                                                                                                               
    --> src\handlers.rs:46:36
     |
46   |     let inserted = coll.insert_one(serialized_news, None).await.unwrap();
     |                         ---------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Borrow<News>` is not implemented for `Bson`
     |                         |
     |                         required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
note: required by a bound in `mongodb::Collection::<T>::insert_one`
    --> C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\mongodb-2.3.1\src\coll\mod.rs:1279:19
     |
1279 |         doc: impl Borrow<T>,
     |                   ^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `mongodb::Collection::<T>::insert_one`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.  
error: could not compile `backend` due to previous error
```

My handler code containing the post_news function that throws this error:

```rust
use crate::structs::News;
use axum::{extract::Path, extract::State, http::StatusCode, response::IntoResponse, Json};
use bson::oid::ObjectId;
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use mongodb::{bson::doc, options::FindOptions, Client, Collection};

pub async fn get_all(State(client): State<Client>) -> impl IntoResponse {
    let coll: Collection<News> = client.database("axum").collection::<News>("news");

    let mut options = FindOptions::default();
    options.limit = Some(1);
    options.sort = Some(doc! {
        "title": 1
    });

    let mut cursor = coll
        .find(None, options)
        .await
        .expect("could not load news data.");

    let mut rows: Vec<News> = Vec::new();

    while let Some(doc) = cursor.next().await {
        rows.push(doc.expect("could not load news info."));
    }

    (StatusCode::OK, Json(rows))
}

pub async fn get_one(Path(id): Path<u64>) {}

pub async fn post_news(
    State(client): State<Client>,
    Json(payload): Json<News>,
) -> impl IntoResponse {
    let coll: Collection<News> = client.database("axum").collection::<News>("news");

    let news = News {
        id: ObjectId::new(),
        title: payload.title.to_string(),
        short_description: payload.short_description.to_string(),
    };

    let serialized_news = bson::to_bson(&news).unwrap();

    let inserted = coll.insert_one(serialized_news, None).await.unwrap();

    (StatusCode::CREATED, Json(news))
}

pub async fn handler_404() -> impl IntoResponse {
    (StatusCode::NOT_FOUND, "nothing to see here")
}

mod structs {
    use bson::{self, oid::ObjectId};
    use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

    #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
    #[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
    pub struct News {
        #[serde(rename = "_id")]
        pub id: ObjectId,
        pub title: String,
        pub short_description: String,
    }
}
```

The error occurs in this line in the `post_news` function:

```rust
let inserted = coll.insert_one(serialized_news, None).await.unwrap();
```

Tried to add `Clone` and `Debug` to my struct and that didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When encountering an error, you need to dig in and figure out *why* the error occurs, rather than just fiddling left and right.

In this case, the first step is looking at the function you are attempting to call [`Collection::insert_one`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/2.3.1/mongodb/struct.Collection.html#method.insert_one):

> ```
> pub async fn insert_one(
>     &self,
>     doc: impl Borrow<T>,
>     options: impl Into<Option<InsertOneOptions>>
> ) -> Result<InsertOneResult>
> ```

And double checking what `Borrow` is by following the link -- just to make sure it's indeed `std::borrow::Borrow` (spoiler: it is).

So, since your `coll` is of type `Collection<News>`, you need a type implementing `Borrow<News>` -- as mentioned by the error message -- which means amongst others `News` and `&News`.

Hence, as shown in the documentation of [`Collection`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/2.3.1/mongodb/struct.Collection.html#), you should just insert your `News` object, **without** first serializing it:

```rust
let inserted = coll.insert_one(news, None).await.unwrap();
```

`Collection` will take care of serializing and deserializing as appropriate, no need to do the `bson` step yourself.